# need explanation in structure C programming, doesn't understand code

Tags: c, structure

```
struct  abc
{
  char name[20];
  int studno;
  float tax;
} rec1, rec2;
```

I just started structure and teacher doesn't teach well, I need help on clarifying the codes. Correct me if I'm wrong thanks.

So struct abc = structure's name?
and it contains 3 fields, an array,integer for student no,and floating type for tax
and what is rec1,rec2 for?? and If the rec1,rec2 are both *rec1,*rec2, what's the difference??

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QUESTIONS:

1. **Is `struct abc` the structure's name?** Yes, it is.
2. **Does `struct abc` contain three fields?** Yes, it does. The structure elements are: `name` (a character array of a fixed size of 20), an integer that holds the student's number: `studno`, and `tax` - which is a float variable.
3. **What is `rec1` and `rec2` for?** `rec1` and `rec2` are simply variable instances of `struct abc`. It is a shorthand way of automatically declaring two variables the same time the structure is defined. For example, to declare a variable afterward using the same structure definition, you would do so as follows:

   ```
   struct abc mystruct = {};//initialize the struct variable mystruct
   ```
4. **If `rec1` and `rec2` are both `*rec1` and `*rec2` - what's the difference?** In this case you've created two pointer variables of the type `struct abc`. This means they can point to variables or instances of `struct abc` as opposed to `rec1` and `rec2` which are only instances of `struct abc`.

DISCUSSION:

For Point 4), in practice this means:

EXAMPLE 1

```
struct abc mystruct = {};
mystruct.name = "My Name";
```

However, since a pointer can *point* to memory, and `rec1` and `rec2` are pointers of type struct abc, this means that you can point to variables or instances of `struct abc`. A common usage would then be:

EXAMPLE 2

```
struct abc mystruct = {};
mystruct.name = "My Name";

struct abc *abc_pointer = &mystruct;//abc_pointer is now _pointing_ to mystruct
```

to access the structure elements, instead of using the dot / access operator as you normally would in a regular structure in the 1st and 2nd examples, you have to do differently, using the **pointer-to-member** operator:

EXAMPLE 3:

```
struct abc *abc_pointer = &mystruct;//abc_pointer is now _pointing_ to mystruct
abc_pointer->name = "Steve";//because you're pointing to mystruct, you can access and modify the values within. In this case, we're changing the name from "My Name" to "Steve"
```

Another way for doing this is:

```
(*abc_pointer).name = "Steve";
```

**Of course, there is much more than what I described that you can do with this knowledge *and* power.** For more on the topic, read the following:
http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Answer (score 0):

`rec1` and `rec2` are two variables you have created with that `struct abc` type.

You could just as easily separate the structure specificion from the variable creation with:

```
struct  abc {
    char name[20];
    int studno;
    float tax;
};

struct abc rec1, rec2;
```

If you were to define a variable as:

```
struct abc *rec3;
```

then `rec3` would be a *pointer* type which was meant to point to a variable of type `struct abc`.